# How can I check whether I have access to JBoss web console on a Unix environment over SSH

Tags: linux, unix, jboss, ssh, console

I've tried numerous google searches but nothing useful came up...I'm connecting via SSH and would like to see if I have access to the JBoss web console. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

A first try would be:

lynx http://localhost:8080/web-console

A second try would be to connect with ssh -X and then:

firefox http://localhost:8080/web-console